# IF statement to exclude blanks

Tags: excel-formula

I have a simple if statement to track yes/no for a pivot table. Sometimes this question does not apply and the user leaves it blank. When the field is blank the field defaults as no (2). If the field is blank I want the statement to ignore it. How do I do that?

=IF(K1239="Yes",1,2)

[Picture of the excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouvIN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should tell Excel supposed to do when the cell is empty

You can use IFS instead of IF function:

```
=IFS(A8="Yes","the value is YES",A8="No","the value is No",A8="","the value is Empty")
```

or

```
=IFS(A10="Yes",1,A10="No",2,A10="",0)
```

Or nested IF:

```
=IF(A11="Yes",1,IF(A11="No",2,0))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the fist IFS statement you suggested but I am getting a #NAME error. I copied formula directly from your example. The only thing I changed was the cell reference.

Comment: It looks like you may have older version of Excel - in that case you need to use nested IF. IFS function is available in newer versions (Excel 365, Excel 2021 according to documentation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45).